# Adding hashes to array in Ruby only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, hash

I'm trying to parse a rather large file of JSON and am now trying to created an array of hashes that I can I can have my Rails UI parse later on.

(trying to only add the relevant JSON)

```
  {
  "CVE_data_type" : "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format" : "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs" : "2203",
  "CVE_data_timestamp" : "2017-09-08T16:01Z",
  "CVE_Items" : [ {
    "cve" : {
      "CVE_data_meta" : {
        "ID" : "CVE-2006-0441"
      },
      "affects" : {
        "vendor" : {
          "vendor_data" : [ {
            "vendor_name" : "automatedlogic",
            "product" : {
              "product_data" : [ {
                "product_name" : "webctrl",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "5.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "5.2",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.1",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.0",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  } ]
                }
              }, {
                "product_name" : "i-vu",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "5.2",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "5.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.0",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  } ]
                }
              }, {
                "product_name" : "sitescan_web",
                "version" : {
                  "version_data" : [ {
                    "version_value" : "5.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.5",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "5.2",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  }, {
                    "version_value" : "6.1",
                    "version_affected" : "<="
                  } ]
                }
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
      },
```

I've been able to build this, however I'm not sure how it's coming up with the incorrect `version` values.  Plus, it's creating the same entry 3 times (I assume because there are 3 `product_name` values:

```
["{\"product_name\"=>\"webctrl\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"i-vu\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"sitescan_web\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}"]
["{\"product_name\"=>\"webctrl\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"i-vu\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"sitescan_web\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}"]
["{\"product_name\"=>\"webctrl\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"i-vu\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}", "{\"product_name\"=>\"sitescan_web\", \"versions\"=>[\"<= 5.5,\", \"<= 6.1,\", \"<= 5.2,\", \"<= 6.5,\", \"<= 6.0,\"]}"]
```

You'll notice that the values aren't correlating between the raw JSON and the output, and that no matter the `product_name` the values are always the same amongst the 3 products returned in each hash within the array.

Here is my code:

```
 data['CVE_Items'].each do |d|
  # setups up needed arrays
  reference_data = []
  product_names = []
  product_info = Hash.new


  # identifying CVE code (use this for lookup with exploit db?)
  cve_id = d['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID']

  # vendor name of the product, defaults to 'Unknown' if not found
  vendor_name = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name'] rescue "Unknown"
  begin
    product_name = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'].each do |n|
      product_info = Hash.new
      product_info['product_name'] = n['product_name'] rescue "Unknown"

      versions_affected = []
      versions = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'][0]['version']['version_data'].each do |v|
        versions_affected << "#{v['version_affected']} #{v['version_value']},"
      end

      product_info['versions'] = versions_affected
      product_affected << "#{product_info}"
    end
  rescue
    "Unknown"
  end
 end

 puts product_affected
```

I'm trying to make the code flexible since some of the JSON output (not included) only has 1 product, 1 version, etc.

Also, is there a better way to iterate over a `product_name` and get the parallel `version` information that I need?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: @ruby_newbie added the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems here are your use of the static index `0` in nearly all of your references. This line will only ever grab the first `vendor_data` and look for its name, no matter how many `vendor_data` are in that array because you use `['vendor_data'][0]`:

```
vendor_name = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['vendor_name']
```

This next line, again, only loops through the `['product']['product_data']` of the first vendor in `vendor_data` because of `['vendor_data'][0]`:

```
product_name = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'].each do |n|
```

Lastly, this next line will run once for each product in `['product']['product_data']` but only ever gets the `['version']['version_data']` for the first product in it (and only ever in the first vendor in `['vendor_data']`):

```
versions = d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'][0]['product']['product_data'][0]['version']['version_data'].each do |v|
```

What you probably want to do is just change everything to loop through all the arrays present, and not worry about specific indexes, something like:

```
data['CVE_Items'].each do |d|
  # identifying CVE code (use this for lookup with exploit db?)
  cve_id = d['cve']['CVE_data_meta']['ID']

  d['cve']['affects']['vendor']['vendor_data'].each do |vendor|
    vendor_name = vendor.fetch('vendor_name', "Unknown")

    vendor['product']['product_data'].each do |product|
      product_info = {
        'product_name' => product.fetch('product_name', 'Unknown'),
        'versions' => []
      }

      product['version']['version_data'].each do |version|
        product_info['versions'] << "#{version['version_affected']} #{version['version_value']},"
      end

      product_affected << "#{product_info}"
    end
  end
end
```

seems to be working, to my untrained-in-your-system eye. I've removed all the irrelevant code from your sample as well, if those are needed outside of the posted example, you'll just need to add them back in.